# Rails: How can I configure to routes.rb for /:id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am working on my personal site with RoR.
I searched and read books. But I cannot figure out.

How Can I configure routes.rb for xxxxx.com/:id?

For example:
twitpic.com's image url or short url is "http://twitpic.com/11u1cy".

Answer (score 2):

```
map.connect ':id', :controller => :your_controller, :action => :show
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming what you mean is that you want a URL like http://example.com/123 to load http://example.com/mymodel/123. If that is the case, put this at the end of your routes:

```
map.mymodel_id '/:id', :controller => 'mymodels', :action => 'show', :requirements => { :id => /\d+/}
```